# Iframe content is a form

Tags: html, css, iframe

I've a form inside iframe like this

```
<iframe id="iframeid" style="display: none;height: 46px;width: 100px;" srcdoc="<html><body>
    <form action='https://localhost/lms/public/user/edit' method='POST'>
        <input type='hidden' name='Username' id='Username' value='tese@gmail.com' />
        <input type='submit' value='Edit Profile' /><
    </form></body></html>"></iframe>
```

But on form submit, it is not redirecting to the server where my form submit is. Is it possible in iframe?

Comment: Why are you creating form in Iframe, it has Cross-domain issues? what is requirement?

Comment: client has asked me to do this "You may be able to iFrame the edit profile button, and using jquery only showing the pop up alert to attach the image. "

Comment: title isn't a question...just a vague statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend not using an iframe for a a form. If a client asked for this, please advise them not to. So many reasons why that's bad.